# UNIRest: switch to a new ViewController on an Asynchronous HTTP response

Tags: ios, objective-c, unirest

I'm using the `UNIRest library` and I'm trying to switch to another `ViewController` on the response of an `HTTP GET method`.

```
[[UNIRest get:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
        [request setUrl:GEtFamilyMembers];
    }] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse* response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"res: %@", response.body);
        if (response.code == 200) {
            GCHFamilyMembersViewConroller* fmViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gchFamilyMembers"];

            self.navigationController.viewControllers = @[fmViewController];
            [self.mm_drawerController setCenterViewController:self.navigationController withCloseAnimation:YES completion:nil];
        } else {
            [self showToast:@"Something went wrong, Please try again after some time."];
        }
    }];
```

Even after printing the response using `NSLog`. Nothing happens for about 30 seconds. Then suddenly app crashes.

I thought it's because Asynch call blocks `UI` so I tired a method like:

```
- (void) gotoSelectFamilyMembers {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        GCHFamilyMembersViewConroller* fmViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gchFamilyMembers"];
        self.navigationController.viewControllers = @[fmViewController];
        [self.mm_drawerController setCenterViewController:self.navigationController withCloseAnimation:YES completion:nil];
    });
}
```

but still the app crashes.

Earlier when I was using a `Synchronous` call it was working. But not now. 
Please help!

EDIT:

```
2016-05-02 17:58:22.695 Checkme Mobile[6208:136321] *** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44.2/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:374
2016-05-02 17:58:22.728 Checkme Mobile[6208:136224] NSScanner: nil string argument
2016-05-02 17:58:22.728 Checkme Mobile[6208:136224] NSScanner: nil string argument
2016-05-02 17:58:23.730 Checkme Mobile[6208:136224] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001094a6c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108da2bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001094a6aca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001089b798f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000107d887d6 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] + 151
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000107829912 -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:] + 473
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000107ad44ad -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 1002
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000107adc834 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _preserveInputViewsWithId:animated:reset:] + 504
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010778e181 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didStartTransition:] + 578
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001079948bc -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 655
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000107792170 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 2984
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000107792408 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 523
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000107792ece -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001078dd6d5 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001076b09eb -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 536
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109d83ed2 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109d786e6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109d78556 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109ce486e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109ce5a22 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 462
    20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109ce5c99 _ZN2CA11Transaction14release_threadEPv + 199
    21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010a35172a _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 86
    22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010a351451 _pthread_exit + 117
    23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010a3506cd _pthread_wqthread + 879
    24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010a34e40d start_wqthread + 13
)
2016-05-02 17:58:23.730 Checkme Mobile[6208:136321] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001094a6c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108da2bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001094a6aca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001089b798f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000107d887d6 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] + 151
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000107829912 -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:] + 473
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000107ad44ad -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 1002
libc++abi.dylib:    7   UIKit                               0x0000000107adc834 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _preserveInputViewsWithId:animated:reset:] + 504
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010778e181 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didStartTransition:] + 578
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001079948bc -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 655
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000107792170 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 2984
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000107792408 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 523
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000107792ece -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001078dd6d5 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001076b09eb -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 536
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109d83ed2 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109d786e6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109d78556 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109ce486e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109ce5a22 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 462
    20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109ce5c99 _ZN2CA11Transaction14release_threadEPv + 199
    21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010a35172a _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 86
    22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010a351451 _pthread_exit + 117
    23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010a3506cd _pthread_wqthread + 879
    24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010a34e40d start_wqthread + 13
)
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSExceptionlibc++abi.dylib: 
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

EDit:

```
- (IBAction)loginAction:(id)sender {
    self.email = usernameTextField.text;
    self.password = passwordTextField.text;
    if(!([self.email isEqualToString:@""] && [self.password isEqualToString:@""])) {
        [self performLogin];
    } else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"Enter both username and password." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void) performLogin {
    NSDictionary* headers = @{@"Content-Type": @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"};
    NSDictionary* parameters = @{@"username": self.email, @"password": self.password};
     [[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread] ? NSLog(@"1MAIN THREAD") : NSLog(@"1NOT MAIN THREAD");
    self.loginConnection = [[UNIRest post:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
        [request setUrl:LOgin];
        [request setHeaders:headers];
        [request setParameters:parameters];
    }] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse* response, NSError *error) {
        // This is the asyncronous callback block
         [[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread] ? NSLog(@"2MAIN THREAD") : NSLog(@"2NOT MAIN THREAD");
        UNIJsonNode *body = response.body;
        NSData *rawBody = response.rawBody;
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:rawBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"response signup: %@", string);
        if (response.code == 200) {
            [self processLoginResponse:body];
        }
    }];

}


- (void) processLoginResponse:(UNIJsonNode *) body {
    if ([body.JSONObject[@"status"] boolValue] == YES) {
        NSString *firstName = body.JSONObject[@"firstName"];
        NSString *lastName = body.JSONObject[@"lastName"];
        NSString *name = [firstName stringByAppendingString:lastName];
        NSMutableDictionary *mDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [mDictionary setObject:body.JSONObject[@"accountId"] forKey:@"accountId"];
        [mDictionary setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
        [mDictionary setObject:@"Custodian" forKey:@"relation"];
        [self fetchFamilyMembers:mDictionary];
    } else {
        [self showAlert:body.JSONObject[@"message"]];
    }
}

- (void) fetchFamilyMembers:(NSMutableDictionary *) mDictionary {
     [[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread] ? NSLog(@"3MAIN THREAD") : NSLog(@"3NOT MAIN THREAD");
    self.fmConnection = [[UNIRest get:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
        [request setUrl:GEtFamilyMembers];
    }] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse* response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"res: %@", response.body);
        if (response.code == 200) {
             [[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread] ? NSLog(@"4MAIN THREAD") : NSLog(@"4NOT MAIN THREAD");
            NSData *rawBody = response.rawBody;
            NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:rawBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"family signup: %@", string);
            [[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread] ? NSLog(@"5MAIN THREAD") : NSLog(@"5NOT MAIN THREAD");
            [self processFamilyMembersResponse:mDictionary :response.body];

        } else {
            [self showToast:@"Something went wrong, Please try again after some time."];
        }
    }];
}

- (void) processFamilyMembersResponse:(NSMutableDictionary *) mDictionary :(UNIJsonNode *) body {

    NSArray *fmArray = body.JSONArray;
    if (fmArray == nil || [fmArray count] == 0) {
        NSNumber *accountId = (NSNumber *)[mDictionary objectForKey:@"accountId"];

    } else {
        NSMutableArray *mArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [mArray addObject:mDictionary];
        for (int i = 0; i < fmArray.count; i++) {
            NSDictionary *fmDictionary = [fmArray objectAtIndex:i];
            mDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            NSNumber *accountId = (NSNumber *)[fmDictionary objectForKey:@"id"];
            [mDictionary setObject:accountId forKey:@"accountId"];
            [mDictionary setObject:[fmDictionary objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
            [mDictionary setObject:[fmDictionary objectForKey:@"relation"] forKey:@"relation"];
            [mArray addObject:mDictionary];
        }
        [[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread] ? NSLog(@"6MAIN THREAD") : NSLog(@"6NOT MAIN THREAD");
        [self gotoSelectFamilyMembers:mArray];
    }

}

- (void) gotoSelectFamilyMembers:(NSMutableArray *) mArray {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        GCHFamilyMembersViewConroller* fmViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gchFamilyMembers"];
        fmViewController._tblData = mArray;
        self.navigationController.viewControllers = @[fmViewController];
        [self.mm_drawerController setCenterViewController:self.navigationController withCloseAnimation:YES completion:nil];
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the error when it crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        GCHFamilyMembersViewConroller* fmViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gchFamilyMembers"];
        fmViewController._tblData = mArray;

        ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]).navigationController.viewControllers = @[fmViewController];
        [self.mm_drawerController setCenterViewController:((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]).navigationController withCloseAnimation:YES completion:nil];
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the asynchronous calls of `Unirest` and the response should be called on the `UI thread (Main thread)`. Usually libraries similar to this deliver the result on the main thread. Therefore, I think you do not need to specifically call `dispatch_async` on the `main queue`. However, you can use the following check to see whether it gets called on the main thread or not.

```
 [[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread] ? NSLog(@"MAIN THREAD") : NSLog(@"NOT MAIN THREAD");
```

Here's what I suspect

1. Your `ViewController` creation method has some fault and is consuming time
2. Your response is very large

I suggest that you call the following without any web service calls to confirm that they do not cause the crash.

```
GCHFamilyMembersViewConroller* fmViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gchFamilyMembers"];

            self.navigationController.viewControllers = @[fmViewController];
            [self.mm_drawerController setCenterViewController:self.navigationController withCloseAnimation:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Yes it is working without web calls. And I did say in my post that I did work with Synchronous a call

Comment: Hi, I modified my answer which includes a way to check whether an executing block is being executed on the main thread or not.

Can you please check with that because I see from your log, a certain possibility of a non-main thread being used to update UI.

Comment: Well, it is printing NOT MAIN THREAD. How do I go back to the main thread?

Comment: Really? Can you also confirm that you're calling the Unirest get method on the main thread? 
ie: Put the check before you call the web service call.

Comment: And I also I'm calling this async task from the response of another async task.

Comment: Well what you've done is technically correct to call the main thread. 
But, can you also check whether you're calling the web service above, from the main thread too?

Comment: Can u post the logs which displays what gets printed for the values of the NSThread isMainThread?

E.g: 1.MAIN THREAD
2. NOT MAIN THREAD etc